# Couldn't switch map view on google map for portrait orientation

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps

I have google map on my site. I added it according to [Google Map Tutorial.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en)

I tried open my page in browser from iPhone. I noticed that I couldn't switch between Map/Satellite view, when iPhone has portrait orientation. On portrait orientation my map look like this and I couldn't chose anything in comboBox:

[image]

On landscape orientation my map look like this and I can switch view, all work fine:

[image]

How I can switch map view on portrait orientation?

Here my html:

```
<div class="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
```

Here my code:

```
            var
            me = this,
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
            map,
            mapOptions = {
                zoom     : 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            },
            $mapContainer = me.$el.find( '.map' );

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': me.model.addressString}, function ( results, status ) {
            if ( status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
                map = new google.maps.Map( $mapContainer[0], mapOptions );
                map.setCenter( results[0].geometry.location );
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
                    map     : map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                } );
            }
        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of bug is that I use fastclick in my application. I found open and not closed bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5677) :

I found next solution: we should add class 'needsclick' dynamically to google maps div childs:

```
 $( document ).on( 'touchstart', '.map', function ( event ) {
            event.target.classList.add( 'needsclick' );
            $( document ).one( 'touchend', function () {
                event.target.classList.remove( 'needsclick' );
            } );
        } );
```

After it all works correctly. Full stack of discussion [here](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/issues/119).